# How to import a class method into a React class

Tags: javascript, reactjs

This works:

main.jsx

```
class Sample extends React.Component {
    getData(){
    }    

    ComponentWillMount(){
        this.getData()
    }
}
```

How do I import and export getData from another file? Say, for example:

helper.js into main.jsx?

Comment: You could define it in the file as `export const getData()`.

Comment: You cannot import or export a class method. You can import or export regular functions just like anything else

Answer (score 1):

Both Colin and Roy With Silver Wings speak truth.

in helper.js you can export constants, helper methods and the like:

```
export const getData() {
  return [1, 2, 3];
}

export const multiplier = 4;
```

Then, in your main.jsx:

```
import (getData, multiplier} from "path/to/helper.js";

class Sample extends React.Component {

  componentWillMount(){
    var myData = Object.assign({}, getData());
    my newData = myData.map(function(x) { return x * multiplier; });
    console.log("multiples:", newData);
  }
}
```